# How do I cancel mrJob once it's running? ^C doesn't work

Tags: mrjob

Is there a simple way to make mrJob scripts interruptable?  Pretty simple question, but it makes a big difference for debugging.  I'm mainly interested in canceling python-only test jobs, because this is where most debugging happens.

```
python my_mr_script.py my-mr-input.txt
```

Comment: Shooting from the hip: try ctrl-\ (aka SIGQUIT).

Comment: Works on my mac.  Nice!  It does open a dialog that says "Python quit unexpectedly." and asks me to report the error.  Minor pain, but not nearly as bad as waiting 10 minutes for a buggy script to finish.

Comment: Cool! I will expand this into a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few easy options:

- Send `SIGQUIT` (that's `ctrl-\` in your terminal).  Most processes don't bother catching `SIGQUIT`, so it's one strategy to deal with something that has a less-than-awesome `SIGINT` (aka `ctrl-c`) handler.
- `ctrl-z` + `kill -9 %1` - aka, the nuclear option.  Even more rare than catching `SIGQUIT` is catching [`SIGTSTP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP#SIGTSTP).  That's what your shell uses to do job control.  In this case you're suspending the job and then sending it `SIGKILL`, which it cannot catch.

N.b. that the `%1` above is a bash-ism and it assumes this is the only job running.